# How can I move an Azure Devops organization to a different organization?

Tags: azure-devops

My non-tech-savvy firm is in the process of recreating our Active Directory. After a take-over they're removing the old domain and recreating it under our new mother company. With this will come new user accounts. This is something that is happening and that I can't stop.

However, we're currently using Azure Devops as our DevOps environment. I'm currently in the process of trying to move our entire organization to my personal Microsoft accounts "Default Directory" (which doesn't have any Visual Studio subscription or whatsoever). This does give me a warning that the users in my old directory won't be able to access it.
My idea is to move the organization back to the newly created Active Directory after the recreation is done.

My question: Is this a good way of doing this, or are there any better solutions for this scenario?

Comment: I don't know the answer here, and don't know if this is even a reasonable suggestion. Would you be willing to try and get a [Visual Studio Enterprise monthly subscription](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vs-enterprise-monthly#overview)? It's a bit pricey, but for just a couple of months.... With that, I wonder if you wouldn't have the admin priviledges to give access to whoever needs it in the interum until you are able to migrate everything back.